# NetBeans is Showing Error file could cause outofmemoryerror netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, out-of-memory

Hello I am using netbeans editor for my Java Desktop application and i am getting error i mean warning like this

```
opening this file could cause outofmemoryerror netbeans
```

This warning shows up because I have a file containing code which is >1MB. And after that I am not able to see error too its not pointing so how could i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the file size of the file you're trying to open? The only time I have seen this is when the file Netbeans is going to open is relatively large (not sure what threshold Netbeans uses to show this warning).

If it's a large text file with data you're reading (or writing) with your software, open it outside of Netbeans with something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

**Update**

Okay, so it's clear now that a file that contains code is relatively large, and Netbeans is already warning you that it might be too large to be opened. I strongly recommend that you split that file into multiple files (multiple classes maybe)?

Example:

**Old situation**

```
public class Class1
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //do stuff (1)
        //do stuff (2)
    }
}
```

**New situation**

```
public class Class1
{

    private NewClass1 newClass1;
    private NewClass2 newClass2;
    private JComponent jComponent;

    public Class1()
    {
        newClass1 = new NewClass1();
        newClass2 = new NewClass2();
        //instantiating jComponent
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        newClass1.doSomethingSmaller(jComponent); //possibly with some return value
        newClass2.doSomethingSmallerToo(jComponent); //possibly with some return value
    }
}

public class NewClass1
{
    public void doSomethingSmaller(JComponent jComponent)
    {
        //do stuff (1)
        jComponent.doStuff();
    }
}

public class NewClass2
{
    public void doSomethingSmallerToo(JComponent jComponent)
    {
        //do stuff (2)
        jComponent.doOtherStuff();
    ]
}
```

Those new classes should then be in separate files, which reduces the size of your file. It also encourages reusing (parts of) your code in other places in your code.

Comment: ya but the thing is that file is >1mb but that is my code na i can not reduce it and is it that all computer will show this error. ?

Comment: If a file with code is >1MB, you should consider splitting that file into multiple files (multiple classes).

Comment: But i have spilt that into the other class but i can not Spilt componemt methods na?

Comment: Well ya that is one of the good solution that can be considerable in to the system.

Comment: +1 Because that is true and netbeans not providing any other good way to prevent it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't reduce your class size try to add this in your **\NetBeans\harness\etc\app.conf**

```
default_options="-J-Xms24m -J-Xmx1024m"
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the core problem, it just hides a warning.

Comment: ohh let me try then. its hides only isn't it?

Comment: Yes, this should prevent Netbeans from showing that warning for now. However, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it hides it, but i recommend to follow Stefan's answer. It's the best way to optimize your code.

Comment: @Stefan okey. but what if there is only methods which is only related to the component of the Swing.

Comment: You can pass the instance of that Swing component to those methods. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Stefan Right it just that i was too lazy to make this major changes haha :P now its done. :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just got this warning and i was not able to open it directly from a reference to that class's method.
so i did this to open(in case if its not opening through reference from a class)
Go to Navigator ->
locate file ->
open , click YES